# Computing integral with integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to figure out the example below, but I still cannot get the right result (I don't know it though, I am just sure this is not the right one).
[image]

What should be the proper procedure to solve this example?

Thank you very much

Comment: If $u=x^2$, then $u'=2x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the integration by parts two times: if

$$\int x^2 \sin x dx$$

then $u=x^2 \Rightarrow du=2x dx$ and $dv=\sin x dx \Rightarrow v=-\cos x$. Then,
$$\int x^2 \sin x dx =-x^2\cos x-\int -\cos x \cdot 2x dx=-x^2\cos x+2\int x\cos x dx. $$

Now, $u=x \Rightarrow du =dx$ and $dv=\cos xdx \Rightarrow v=\sin x$ and so 
$$\int x^2\sin x dx = -x^2\cos x+2\left( x\sin x -\int \sin x dx\right)= $$
$$=-x^2\cos x+2x\sin x+2\cos x +c. $$

Note that this exercise which "bothered him" the question was the factor $ x ^ 2 $, so we apply integration by parts twice to "extract" this factor.

Comment: Thank you, man, for your answer. There's one thing I don't understand - in the end of the 2nd line of computing, there's "xsinxdx" - but in the previous step is "-cosx2xdx" - how has there appeared the "sinx"?

Comment: That should be $\cos(x)$, not $\sin(x)$.  As written, there is a mistake in that line.

Comment: sorry, was a typographical error, already I arranged.